# Linux won't wake up from suspend on intel alder latke + gigabyte Z690

Tags: linux, suspend, intel

I've recently bought a core i5 12600K and a Gigabyte Z690

I can't get ubuntu 21.10 suspend working properly. System suspend, then when I wake it up, screen stays dark even though my computer "seem" to start (fan are on again as well as RGB) and I need to fully restart the computer.

I'm currently on Ubuntu 21.10 running 5.13 kernel but I've tried 5.16 as well, I've also tried latest Manjaro, same issue there, that's why I don't think it is related to ubuntu itself.

I've enabled S3 suspend on Bios

Suspend works well on Windows

I don't know what I should try to do after that, any ideas ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a workaround right there

https://forum.manjaro.org/t/suspend-problems-with-lpss-on-alder-lake-cpu/98107

with a

`sudo rmmod intel_lpss_pci`

be careful with that, I don't now what could be impacted by this

Answer (score 1):

Disabling '`IOAPIC 24-119`' in BIOS settings on my Gigabyte Z690 worked for me.
Thanks to post by kiloba https://forum.manjaro.org/t/suspend-problems-with-lpss-on-alder-lake-cpu/98107

Comment: Thank you so much! I managed to fix that nasty issue after searching for a solution for over 6 months.